# Android Studio - Missing class declarations in target API's classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3, currently developing an app with the following build conditions as found in app's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gery.syncadaptercustomtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the app is targeting API 24. I've installed (I think) every required SDK components:

- Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.3
- Sources for Android 24
- Android SDK Platform 24
- Google APIs (for API Level 24)

In my app, I'm using one of the methods of the native `AccountManager` class. If I jump to the declaration of the `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly()` method, this is what I can see:

[image]

As you can see on the scrolling area on right side, several declarations are missing, like they would not be imported to the class. For example, on line 733 the `mService` field has a class type which Android Studio cannot find, so the method is missing too (says 'Cannot resolve method...' when hovering the mouse over it). And this is how the field's missing class type looks like (on line 269):

[image]

I've tried to reinstall every SDK component, even tried File > Invalidate Caches / Restart several times, but the problem is still there. I didn't find anything similar to this on SO, nor anywhere else. Do someone know what is happening?

---

**UPDATE 1:** After the answer of DKIT I've looked around in the Android Developers class reference, searching for the `IAccountManager` class, but it's nowhere - I have no idea what this could be and what would it refer to. Moreover, the `AccountManager` class was introduced in API Level 5 with most of it's methods, including `addAccountExplicitly()`; so I cannot see any reason why it would not exist on any nowadays common device.

By the way, the following classes are "unimported" too in `AccountManager` (technically they are in the `import` section, but their declarations are also missing). Maybe this helps...

- `android.annotation.NonNull`
- `android.annotation.RequiresPermission`
- `android.annotation.Size`
- `android.annotation.SystemApi` (as seen also on Image 2 at line 259)
- `com.google.android.collect.Maps`

---

**UPDATE 2**: The reason why I'm missing so much the inner components in native Android classes is that I would like to know what is happening inside them exactly. I think it would be really simple to look on the working of Android components right here, in Android Studio, however it is possible that this use case / feature is existing somewhere else on the internet I don't know about... :D

Thanks for Ashwin Mothilal in helping me to make this clear for everyone! ;)

Comment: Those images are class files of AccountManager.java right? How could you possibly see their private methods. i.e mService.addAccountExplicitly()

Comment: The images were made inside the AccountManager.java file (the `AccountManager` class itself), you can find it in AS Project Explorer. Sorry, I don't understand your question clearly... :)

Comment: Account Manager is not created by you right? It exists in package android.accounts; It is possible to view their private methods? Absolutely not. Make a call to `public boolean addAccountExplicitly(Account account, String password, Bundle userdata)` and you will get the result and you are not supposed to use this `mService.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, userdata);`

Comment: Thanks, understood what was your point... I've updated my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, Android Studio doesn't allow to see their private members and what is happening inside as mentioned in the comment above.

1. I am sure android studio doesn't allow this according to this question.
2. May be something else can.

I am not sure about the second point but sure about the first one.

> Account Manager is not created by you right? It exists in package android.accounts; It is possible to view their private methods? Absolutely not. Make a call to public boolean addAccountExplicitly(Account account, String password, Bundle userdata) and you will get the result and you are not supposed to use this mService.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, userdata);

Comment: Good to know it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the minSdkVersion to 15.
So if the method you are calling is not present in API Level 15 you will get this warning. You probably have to handle situations where your code is running on a device where this method does not exist by checking API level and do conditional code based on this.